# Общие вхождения или пересечения двух QuerySet Django Q object

Tags: python, django

Есть два сформированных QuerySet, надо сформировать итоговый QuerySet, но только встречающийся там и там. то есть найти пересечения с помощью Q. Ниже будет пример с обычным list, чтобы понять, что я имею ввиду.

**views**

```
filter = 'sometext' 
list1 = Orders.objects.filter(device__in=filter).values_list('related_uuid')
list2 = Clients.objects.filter(name__in=filter).values_list('related_uuid')
conds = Q(related_uuid__in=list1) | Q(related_uuid__in=list2)
return Orders.objects.filter(conds)
# выводит все вхождения list1 и list2, а надо пересечения
```

**пример вывода c list для понимания:**

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,1]
conds = Q(related_uuid__in=list1) | Q(related_uuid__in=list2)
return Orders.objects.filter(conds)
# вывод только записи 1
# пример не рабочий, просто для понимания, что мне надо найти пересечения
```

надо вывести только значение `1`, так как оно встречается в обоих `list`. Как сделать это с помощью `Q`?

Comment: попробуй `queryset1 & queryset2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
conds = Q(related_uuid__in=list1) & Q(related_uuid__in=list2)
```

Рекомендую прочитать про [Django Q Operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/). Можно даже переведенные со старый версий, особо ничего не менялось